# Maven war doesn't have dependent jars and jsps

Tags: maven

I am completely new to build tools. I have to create a war using maven. My project has some dependent jars and jsps. but the resultant war doesn't have these jars and jsps.

Here is my project structure

> TestWeb > src>main>webapp>WEB-INF>lib> all dependent jars
>
> >src>main>webapp> all JSPs

Here is my pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestWeb</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingIncludes>src/main/webapp/*.jsp</packagingIncludes>
                    <packagingIncludes>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingIncludes>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First remove thos packagingIncludes and the webXml configuration from your pom file furthermore use the most recent version of [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) 3.2.0....apart from that can you please show where you have located your jsps ? directory structure ?

Comment: i have my jars under > src>main>webapp>WEB-INF>lib and jsps under src>main>webapp

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. Now I want to package this war into an .ear . What changes are required in my pom.xml